# App Icon doesnt show up in Actionbar (Android Studio 1.0.1)

Tags: android, xml, icons, themes

So I'm pretty new to android development and I just can't get ANY icon to show up in the actionbar.

I create a new project with minimum sdk API 15 and choose "Holo.Light" in the Theme-Dropdown (XML-Design-View).

So I want it to look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfgCq.png

but instead it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dLik.png

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I guess I have to change android:theme to Holo.Light somehow? but theres no ressource defined and I cant seem to add any..

my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
```

The ic_launcher.png is in the drawables folder.. so what do I have to do to get that damn icon to show up?

(I use my HTC one M8 btw, but it doesnt show up on an emulator either)

thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To display the icon on ActionBar you have to add :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

in `onCreate` method.

Comment: thank you, that solved it! Sorry if this is a stupid question.. but where do you learn stuff like this? im currently reading the official android dev beginner tutorials and nowhere is this mentioned..

Comment: Not so stupid, i started with the beginner tutorials, you can improve  your android development knowledge for example in courses like this https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853. If you want you can mark the answer as correct.

Comment: On Android Studio 1.4 the app icon resources (using the wizard New -> Image Asset -> Asset type: Laucher Icons) goes to `res/mipmap` instead of `res/drawable`.

Said that, the code might be:

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

Answer (score 1):

Another way I solve with this code

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```